# Help solving differential equation with squared derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find a solution of the following differential equation?

$$(y')^2=y$$

Thanks!

Comment: $y=\dfrac14 x^2$ is a solution

Comment: @NICOLAS FRANCO RAMPOLDI: **Hint:** Take the square root of each side.

Comment: Solutions to this ODE (even with initial conditions) are not unique. $y=0$ is also a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In implicit equations like this or Clairaut equations it is sometimes helpful to compute the derivative of the equation
$$
2y'y''=y'\iff y'(2y''-1)=0.
$$
This equation is satisfied by functions that can be subdivided into arcs over which one of the factors is zero. That is, either $y'=0$ or $y''=\frac12\implies y'(t)=\frac12t+a$. Now insert into the original equation to get either $y\equiv 0$ or $y(t)=(\frac12t+a)^2$ over the arc under consideration. A switch from one variant to the other can occur at times where both factors are zero, and more importantly, where function value and derivative have the same values, that is, at $t_a=-2a$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a DE like this, you typically want to make the highest derivative term as simple as possible, and work from there. So in this case, if we do that then we can actually derive the solution through direct integration (if that's your thing):

$\begin{eqnarray}(y')^2 & = & y \\
y' & = & \pm y^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = & \pm y^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\frac{dx}{dy} & = & \pm y^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
\int\frac{dx}{dy} dy & = & \pm \int y^{-\frac{1}{2}} dy \\
x & = & \pm 2 y^{\frac{1}{2}} + C \\
\pm y^{\frac{1}{2}} & = & \frac{1}{2}(x - C) \\
y & = & \frac{1}{4}(x - C)^2 \end{eqnarray}$

We can confirm this solution by checking:

$(y')^2 = \left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{4}(x - C)^2\right)\right]^2 = \left[\frac{1}{4} \times 2 \times (x - C)\right]^2 = \left[\frac{1}{2}(x - C)\right]^2 = \frac{1}{4}(x - C)^2 = y$

Comment: Thank you so much! If the exercise says Y(0)=2, Y'(0)=1 is it badly written? When i put those numbers in the answer is absurd

Comment: If y(0)=2 then by the definition of the DE y'(0) = sqrt(2). Either there's a typo, or it's asking for two different solutions.